# disambiguate between function pointer and pointer to class instance

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits

I have a utility which performs a **`static_assert` on whether a  function can be called with a given list of arguments**.

I have 2 overloads:

**for lambdas and free functions:**

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void assert_is_callable(Func&&, Args&&...)
```

**for member functions:**

```
template<typename Class, typename MemFunc, typename... Args>
void assert_is_callable(Class*, MemFunc, Args&&...)
```

The problem I'm having is that when I call `assert_is_callable` with a free function, the 2nd overload is chosen; the function pointer is deduced to be `Class`, the first argument is deduced to be `MemFunc` and the remaining arguments `Args...`

```
void func(int, double, char) {  }

assert_is_callable(func, 1, 2.3, 'c'); // selects the member_function version
```

**Compilation error output:**

```
In instantiation of 'void assert_is_callable(Class*, MemFunc, Args&& ...) [with Class = void(int, double, char); MemFunc = int; Args = {double, char}]':
prog.cpp:79:41:   required from here
prog.cpp:51:5: error: static assertion failed: the provided type is not callable with the supplied arguments
     static_assert(is_callable_member_function<Class, MemFunc, Args...>::value,
     ^
```

### Question:

How can I prevent the member function overload from being selected when using `assert_is_callable` with a free function?

### Example:

[working example on ideone](https://ideone.com/73E1d4)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

// functor

template<class Func, class... Args>
class is_callable
{
    using yes = char(&)[2];
    using no  = char(&)[1];

    template<class F>
    static yes check(decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<Args>()...))*);

    template<class F>
    static no check(...);
public:
    enum { value = (sizeof(check<Func>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes)) };
};

// member function

template<typename Class, typename MemFunc, class... Args>
class is_callable_member_function
{
    using yes = char(&)[2];
    using no  = char(&)[1];

    template<class C, class MF>
    static yes check(decltype((std::declval<C>().*std::declval<MF>())(std::declval<Args>()...))*);

    template<class C, class MF>
    static no check(...);
public:
    enum { value = (sizeof(check<Class, MemFunc>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes)) };
};

//////////////////////////////////

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void assert_is_callable(Func&&, Args&&...)
{
    static_assert(is_callable<Func, Args...>::value,
            "the provided type is not callable with the supplied arguments");
}

template<typename Class, typename MemFunc, typename... Args>
void assert_is_callable(Class*, MemFunc, Args&&...)
{
    static_assert(is_callable_member_function<Class, MemFunc, Args...>::value,
            "the provided type is not callable with the supplied arguments");
}

//////////////////////////////////

struct Foo
{
    void func(int, double, char)
    {
    }
};

void func(int, double, char)
{
}

int main()
{
    // member function
    Foo f;
    assert_is_callable(&f, &Foo::func, 1, 2.3, 'c');

    // lambda
    auto lambda = [](int, double, char) { };
    assert_is_callable(lambda, 1, 2.3, 'c');

    // free function
//    assert_is_callable(func, 1, 2.3, 'c'); // selects the member_function version

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use SFINAE with `!std::is_function<Class>::value`.

Comment: I tried both `is_function` and `is_member_pointer`, but both cause the 1st overload to now be called for member functions. My signature: `void assert_is_callable(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_function<Class>::value>::type*, MemFunc, Args&&...)`

Comment: Use it in the return type. You've disabled template argument deduction.

Comment: Got it, thanks! `template<typename Class, typename MemFunc, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<Class>::value>::type
assert_is_callable(Class*, MemFunc, Args&&...)` - if you want to put that into an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use SFINAE, or use strong type directly:

```
template<typename Class, typename C, typename MemFunc, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<Class>::value>
assert_is_callable(Class*, MemFunc (C::*), Args&&...)
{
    static_assert(is_callable_member_function<Class, MemFunc (C::*), Args...>::value,
            "the provided type is not callable with the supplied arguments");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66e20a3006b66fa1)